# Error when running script to create an image collection

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I am trying to create an image collection and then calculate VCI. When I run the script I got an error which is

> ImageCollection (Error) The input collection must be a collection of
>   collections, but the element with id 2000_09_29 was `<Image<[NDVI]>>`,
>   which is not a collection.

```
//study area call
var shp = ee.FeatureCollection(table);

var collection = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MOD13Q1').select('NDVI');
var filter = ee.Filter.calendarRange(9,9, 'month');
var filtermodis = collection.filter(filter);
//print(filtermodis);
// september 2nd
var mod_2000 = ee.Image('MODIS/006/MOD13Q1/2000_09_29').select('NDVI');
var mod_2001 = ee.Image('MODIS/006/MOD13Q1/2001_09_30').select('NDVI');
var mod_2002 = ee.Image('MODIS/006/MOD13Q1/2002_09_30').select('NDVI');
var mod_2003 = ee.Image('MODIS/006/MOD13Q1/2003_09_30').select('NDVI');
var mod_2004 = ee.Image('MODIS/006/MOD13Q1/2004_09_29').select('NDVI');
var mod_2005 = ee.Image('MODIS/006/MOD13Q1/2005_09_30').select('NDVI');
var mod_2006 = ee.Image('MODIS/006/MOD13Q1/2006_09_30').select('NDVI');
var mod_2007 = ee.Image('MODIS/006/MOD13Q1/2007_09_30').select('NDVI');
var mod_2008 = ee.Image('MODIS/006/MOD13Q1/2008_09_29').select('NDVI');
var mod_2009 = ee.Image('MODIS/006/MOD13Q1/2009_09_30').select('NDVI');
var mod_2010 = ee.Image('MODIS/006/MOD13Q1/2010_09_30').select('NDVI');
var mod_2011 = ee.Image('MODIS/006/MOD13Q1/2011_09_30').select('NDVI');
var mod_2012 = ee.Image('MODIS/006/MOD13Q1/2012_09_29').select('NDVI');
var mod_2013 = ee.Image('MODIS/006/MOD13Q1/2013_09_30').select('NDVI');
var mod_2014 = ee.Image('MODIS/006/MOD13Q1/2014_09_30').select('NDVI');
var mod_2015 = ee.Image('MODIS/006/MOD13Q1/2015_09_30').select('NDVI');
var mod_2016 = ee.Image('MODIS/006/MOD13Q1/2016_09_29').select('NDVI');
var mod_2017 = ee.Image('MODIS/006/MOD13Q1/2017_09_30').select('NDVI');
var mod_2018 = ee.Image('MODIS/006/MOD13Q1/2018_09_30').select('NDVI');
var mod_2019 = ee.Image('MODIS/006/MOD13Q1/2019_09_30').select('NDVI');
//print(mod_2019)

//listing
var mod_list = ee.ImageCollection([mod_2000,mod_2001,mod_2002,mod_2003,mod_2004,mod_2005,
                        mod_2006,mod_2007,mod_2008,mod_2009,mod_2010,mod_2011,mod_2012,
                        mod_2013,mod_2014,mod_2015,mod_2016,mod_2017,mod_2018,mod_2019,]);
 print(mod_list);

 var modis_filtered_flattened = 
    ee.ImageCollection(ee.FeatureCollection(mod_list).flatten());
 print (modis_filtered_flattened)

 // min, max calculation
 var min = modis_filtered_flattened.reduce(ee.Reducer.min());
 var max = modis_filtered_flattened.reduce(ee.Reducer.max());
print(min);

//VCI calculation
var vci = modis_filtered_flattened.map(function(img){
 var id = img.id();
 return img.expression(
   "((NDVI-min)/(max-min))*100",{
     "NDVI" : img,
     "max" : max,
     "min" : min,
   }).copyProperties(img,['system:time_start','system:time_end']);
});
print(vci);
```

Comment: 1. Why do you need to use .flatten()?                         2. What is "vci_jun1", it wasn't defined ?

Comment: I want all the images, that's why I flatten them into one collection and ''vci_jun1'' it just a mistake plz ignore it.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to use `.flatten()`. You have already put together an ImageCollection containing images. Flattening is when you have many *collections* that you want to turn into one. If you remove the flatten and just use `mod_list` instead of `modis_filtered_flattened` in your script, it will run successfully.